# Exact and fuzzy search

Tags: elasticsearch

My setup:

I have some documents with name "Apple", "Apple delicous", ...

This is my query:

```
GET p_index/_search
{
   "query": {
       "bool": {
       "should": [
          {"match": {
             "name": "apple"
          }},
          { "fuzzy": {
            "name": "apple"
          }}
       ]
       }

   }
}
```

I want achieve, that first the exact match is shown and then the fuzzy one:

1. apple
2. apple delicous

Second, i am wondering that i did not get any result if i enter only app in the search:

```
GET p_index/_search
{
   "query": {
       "bool": {
       "should": [
          {"match": {
             "name": "app"
          }},
          { "fuzzy": {
            "name": "app"
          }}
       ]
       }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

1)To give higher score to an exact match you could try adding `"index" : "not_analyzed"` to your `name` field like this.

```
name: {
    type: 'string',
    "fields": {
        "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed" <--- here
        }
    }
}
```

After that your query would look like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "apple"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name.raw": "apple"
          },
          "boost": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will give higher score for document with "apple" than "apple delicous"

2)To better understand `fuzziness` you should go through [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzziness.html) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search) article.

From the Docs

> The fuzziness parameter can be set to AUTO, which results in the
>   following maximum edit distances:
>
> - 0 for strings of one or two characters
> - 1 for strings of three, four, or five characters
> - 2 for strings of more than five characters

So, the reason your `fuzzy query` did not return *apple* for *app* is because `fuzziness` i.e `edit distance` is 2 between those words and since "app" is only three letter word, `fuzziness` value is 1. You could achieve the desired result with following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "name": {
        "value": "app",
        "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I seriously would not recommend using this query, because It will return bizarre results, the above query will return *cap, arm, pip* and lot of other words as they fall within edit distance of 2.

This would better query

```
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "name": {
        "value": "appl"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It will return apple.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think ,This will help you.

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"function_score":{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"airetl","fields":["brand_lower"],"boost":1,"fuzziness":Auto,"prefix_length":1}}}}}]}}
```

Comment: Could you please indent your JSON query to make it readable please